# file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify): failed to open stream: Connection timed out

Tags: php, laravel, server, centos, centos7

I have tried many solution but no one can help. I'm using google recaptcha for my laravel project and i'm using this library `"buzz/laravel-google-captcha": "^2.2"`

Here is it my code in view

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   @php($attributes = [])
      {!! Form::captcha($attributes) !!}
      @if ($errors->has('g-recaptcha-response'))
         <span class="invalid-feedback" style="display: block;">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('g-recaptcha-response') }}</strong>
         </span>
      @endif
</div>
```

My code in LoginController

```
public function validateLogin(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->username() => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
            'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',

        ]);
}
```

I got an error

> file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify): failed to open stream: Connection timed out

I have tried restart my VPS, i have update my secret-key, i have turn on in configuration `allow_url_fopen=On` and `allow_url_include=On`

I still got the error. Anyone can help me? It works fine in localhost

I'm using centos 7, laravel 5.7

Comment: Make sure php can connect to the internet within your VPS

Comment: how i can test it?. i can access my vps so it is connect to the internet right? @user8555937

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't have internet access. Try it with curl for example. Login with SSH and test:

```
curl https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
```

or use telnet

```
telnet https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify 443
```

If there is no connection you can't connect. Then you should check if you have a firewall installed on that system or if you have a firewall in front of your system.

Comment: ohh that's right! i'm not getting anything after trying that curl command. I have installed CSF but how to make my vps can connect internet again?

Comment: I don't know exactly. You try this. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-config-server-firewall-csf-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue using the `google/recaptcha` which `buzz/laravel-google-recaptcha` is based on. Changing the request method has fixed it.

```php
$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha('secret', new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost);
```

I guess you are able to change this in the `buzz/laravel-google-recaptcha` config as well. [Here](https://github.com/thinhbuzz/laravel-google-captcha#custom-recaptcha-request-minimum-version-217).